# floor and ceiling functions.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine whether ‘the set of positive integers that are not divisible by 3’ is
countable or uncountable. If this set is countable, prove it by proposing a bijection (a oneto-
one and onto function) between this set and the set of positive integers (Z+). Please
briefly explain that the function you propose is one-to-one and onto.
Hint: In addition to the arithmetic operators, you are allowed to use floor and ceiling functions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider f: Z+ $\implies$ {x| x is a positive integer that is not divisible by 3} where

$$f(x) = x + \lfloor{\frac{(x- 1)}{2}\rfloor}$$

```
f(x) generates positive integers that are not divisible by 3 from Z+ as can be seen: 
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ...) --> (1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, ...)
```

This function is one-to-one because every element in the codomain has a one pre-image in the domain. This function is also onto because it completely covers the set of positive integers that are not divisible by 3.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the hint: which values does the function
$$
\lfloor\tfrac{1}{3}x\rfloor
$$
take when evaluated on $x=1,2,3,...$? Why will this be helpful in 'skipping' every third number?